# Media query does not work on a phone but does in a desktop browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsiveness

Media query

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    // code
}
```

gets executed when I load the webpage using the Inspect element responsive tester (Firefox). But it does not work when I load the webpage on a mobile device (tried Chrome, Opera GX and Safari).

For clarification, I do have my viewport set with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` and I tried every other meta tag I could find on here.

Comment: You should not be using the device-width properties to begin with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width

Comment: That was just an example, I was using countless recommended meta tags.

Comment: I meant in your media query conditions. Quote from the page I linked to: _"Note: To query for the width of the viewport, developers should use the `width` media feature instead."_

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    // code
}
```